# Black diamonds and question marks persisting after setting database uft8mb4

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, payara, utf8mb4

Regarding MySQL database and Java JDBC connection encoding.
Database has been converted to utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_ci as shown this is the results of `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';` from the JDBC connection.

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
|      Variable_name       |       Value        |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

From the MySQL Workbench and the terminal connecting directly to the DB I can see the Unicode character `í` with its correct hex value of `c3 ad`

```
+------------------------------+
| HEX(location.name)           |
+------------------------------+
| C3AD                         |
+------------------------------+
```

JDBC Connection settings:
`useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Using HikariCP with the config of

`config.addDataSourceProperty("useUnicode", "true");
 config.addDataSourceProperty("characterEncoding", "utf-8");
 config.setConnectionInitSql("SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci");`

Using `mysql-connector-java:8.0.11`

From the results of querying the table in question using the JDBC connection the `í` character is returned as `�` within Postman. And the  is returned as `?` within Postman.

Which leads me to believe that my connection during reading is not UTF-8 according to [stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566) how would I detect this?

Database and application have been reset to apply settings, if it was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

characterEncoding=utf-8 is incompatible with utf8mb4.  Use `character_set_server=utf8mb4` in your JDBC URL instead, or `config.addDataSourceProperty("character_set_server", "utf8mb4");`.  Do not use characterEncoding at all.

From the MySQL Connection/J developer guide → Using Character Sets → [Setting the Character Encoding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html#idm139669163900352):

> … to use the 4-byte UTF-8 character set with Connector/J, configure the MySQL server with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`, and leave `characterEncoding` out of the Connector/J connection string.

And right below that:

> **Warning**
>
> In order to use the `utf8mb4` character set for the connection, the server MUST be configured with `character_set_server=utf8mb4`; if that is not the case, when `UTF-8` is used for `characterEncoding` in the connection string, it will map to the MySQL character set name `utf8`, which is an alias for `utf8mb3`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to following the help from VGR I also was using a normal PrintWriter to send the responses which doesn't allow for UTF-8 encoding.
Instead of

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println(res);
out.flush();
```

Replaced with

```
response.getOutputStream().write(res.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

"`í` character is returned as `�`" is a different issue than " is returned as `?`"

The former usually happens when the byte(s) for `í` were not encoded as UTF-8.  Note that, in MySQL, utf8mb3 and utf8mb4 are identical for the correct encoding of that character and all other European characters.  Fixing the connection (as discussed by VGR) will probably not fix it.  Black diamonds seem to occur only when the browser is not set to UTF-8 (Unicode).

The "pile of poo" is available only in utf8mb4, not utf8mb3.  So, assuming the client correctly had hex `F09F92A9`, then the connection parameters (see VGR) were probably causing the problem.

(More discussion is in the link you provided.)